# Multiple inheritance, traits and properties, how to do this the best way?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, traits

I have some classes to interact with the different types of databases. Each db-class needs to extend some general classes.

Like:

```
<?php
mysql\SelectSql extends common\SelectSqlAbstract
mysql\SqlComposer extends common\SqlComposerAbstract
?>
```

The problem is that `SelectSql` should also extend the SqlComposer-classes.
This is not possible in PHP because it would need multiple-inheritance.

So I am trying a workaround and rewriting `SqlComposer` as a trait. (I also tried to use `SelectSqlAbstract` as trait) Then the structure is:

```
<?php
class mysql\SelectSql extends common\SelectSqlAbstract{
  use mysql\SqlComposerTrait
} 
abstract class common\SelectSqlAbstract extends common\SqlComposerAbstract{
  protected $sqlType = 'select';
}

abstract class common\SqlComposerAbstract{
  protected $sqlType;
  protected $dbType;

}
trait mysql\SqlComposerTrait{
  protected $dbType = 'mysql';
}
?>
```

This is really not best practice and it will give a fatal error.

But how else can I do this? I don't want to get the properties by an function which extract it from the classnames/namespace.

And is there a better way to get this structure when you need 2 types of levels:
specificNS\SpecificClass 
extends commonNs\SpecificClass 
extends specificNs\CommonClass
extends commonNs\CommonClass

Composition wont really help. Because most of the functions will be in de commonNs. Only a few functions will be overridden bij the specificNs

It won't help to alias classes (I think) because I need to use more types of databases in one script...

Comment: Side question - is there any particular reason why you're not using one of the existing ORMs that are available to PHP developers (Eloquent, Doctrine, Propel)?

Comment: thanks for asking. I have this layer for years now, before ORM's where made. 
I am just rewriting it to better OO and smaller classes.
And I have not found (and not looked for) an ORM which can nicely compose sql's and do the specific things we want ;)

Comment: I'm not going to educate you on how to spend your development time but I'll leave you with this - every problem you have, someone else had. Now, if that someone else solved the problem, open sourced it, provided unit tests and if a lot of other people adopted it - it might be extremely smart for you to do so as well or at least try. You will save time, and time = money.

Comment: true, but thats an other discussion ;)
and i am not the only one to decide that :-)

Answer (score 2):

Whether using ORM is the only best practice or staying with one's own code is the way to go is a totally different debate and I am sure there are as many opinions on this as are the number of developers out there.

As you have been with your code for years now, that means it works and you know every bit and piece of your code by now, so stick with what you have and make it better gradually by refactoring.

Now coming to the question, if you are trying to rewrite your DB access logic from scratch and all you want to do is be able to switch databases easily later on without having to modify a pile of classes, I would recommend to have a look at the design patterns other than the one you are stuck with.

For example in your case, try strategy pattern, or builder pattern where you can decide the logic at runtime.
for PHP specific use cases, check https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP 
Composition should definitely help, and rather it will produce more elegant and readable code that the one you are trying to achieve via multiple inheritance.